# pre_replace $23,852.50, remove '$' and ','

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

I have variable which stores price

```
$price = $23,852.50
```

I want to remove $ sign and ',' from my variable, so I can use this number for multiplication, addition and subtraction.

I am trying this

```
echo preg_replace("(\\$)", "", '$23,852.50');
```

Which is removing the $ sign but I don't know how to add ',' with it too.

Answer (score 1):

For this i would just use `str_replace()` just use an array for the first variable.

```
echo str_replace(array("$", ","), "", $price);
```

Comment: +1 for using str_replace instead of preg_replace in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Smith said, you'd better use str_replace, but if you really want to use preg_replace, do:

```
preg_replace("/[$,]+/", "", '$23,852.50');
```

Where `[$,]` is a character class that matches `$` or `,`.

Answer (score 0):

With strtr:

```
$price = strtr($price, array('$'=>'', ','=>''));
```

The advantage of strtr is that the string is parsed only once whatever the number of replace pairs in the array.